# <apex:inputHidden is not capturing the value for a lead field

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have a radio select option which on change assigns the apex input hidden id with the checked value. With this i assign a field in the controller which calls the select option but due to some reason my field in the controller is not getting the value.

- **Visual force Page and JQUERY :-**

  $$(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[name$=programRadio]').change(function() {
          var selectedOpt = this.value;

  ```
  if(selectedOpt != undefined)   
      {           
          $('[id$=hdnProgram]').val(selectedOpt);
          alert($('[id$=hdnProgram]').val());
          ProgramChange();
      }
  ```

  });
    });

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <apex:inputHidden id="selectedPracticeRecord" value="{!selectedPracticeRecord}"/>

    function selectFunction(x) { 
document.getElementById('{!$Component.selectedPracticeRecord}').value = x; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is the value is getting stored in the ID :-

Comment: Hi jai,
The value in the id is sent to {!objLead.program} which conditionally renders a picklist from the controller side
but for some reason the hidden id doesnot store the value in it. by using the console log i got the value using
jQuery('[id$=hdnProgram]').val(selectedOption); where selectedOption is a radio selected value.
Thanks